# How can I set the scrollbar position of the web

Tags: scrollbar, position

How can I set the scrollbar position instead of default on the top

update:I mean that when the user open the web first time the scrollbar is on the top of the screen(it default)

how can I set the scrollbar position(the middle or on the bottom)? so the user can see the

middle of the web or the bottom of the web,How I can do it?

Comment: What OS? Technology? Web or desktop? More specific information, please.

Comment: What OS? What programming language?

Comment: Can you explain more ? What programming language ?

Comment: alot more info required!

Comment: @bgy- what would make you assume css?

Comment: I propose jQuery as a solution!

Comment: @lanqy- the question is what language are you trying to do this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use:

```
<a name="myname" />
```

where you want to scroll to... and reference the page with:

```
www.example.com/mypage.html#myname
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can use anchors as BoltBait sugggested or use javascript's:

```
window.scroll(x,y);
```

Although jQuery has a nice plugin that I would suggest using. 
[Scroll Plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)